# robot framework with appium ( not able identify elements )

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I am trying to automate native android app using robot framework + appium with AppiumLibrary and was able to successfully open application ,from there my struggle begins, not able to find any element on the screen through UI automator viewer since the app which I was testing is web-view context and it shows like a single frame(no elements in it is being identified) . I have spoken to dev team and they gave some html static pages where I could see some element id's for that app. So I have used those id's ,But whenever I ran the test it throws error as element doesn't match . The same app is working with java + appium testNG framework. Only difference I could see between these two is, using java + appium framework complete html code is getting when we call page source method for the android driver object but in robot its returning some xml code which was displayed in UI automator viewer(so this xml doesn't contain any HTML source code with element id's and robot is searching the id's in this xml code and hence it is failing). I am totally confused and got stuck here. Can some one help me on this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Switch to (webview) context resolved this issue.

Comment: How to activate the web view